# TYPO3: CKEditor strips data-attributes in <span>-Tags

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typo3-8.x

I want to use a data-attribute in a span-Tag. The CKEditor removes this attribute.

If I add it in a p-Tag it will not removed and this is OK.

```
processing:
 allowAttributes: [data-count]
```

is added in the YAML-file.

I've tried this and other combinations, nothing works.

```
config
  extraAllowedContent: '*(*)[data-*]'
```

What do I have to do, to keep the data-attribute in a span-Tag?

Comment: did you find a solution? Got the same Problem.
[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58624514/typo3-data-attributes-of-tags-in-ckeditor-configuration-of-my-plugin-are-stripe)

Comment: Sorry, still no solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this for iframe tag with attribbuts, no allowAttributes used for this:

```
processing:
  allowTags:
    - iframe

editor:
  config:    
    extraAllowedContent:
      - iframe[*]
```

for you this should do the trick:

```
editor:
  config:    
    extraAllowedContent:
      - span[*]
```