# TYPO3: Data-attributes of tags in ckeditor configuration of my plugin are striped

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor, typo3-8.x, ckeditor4.x

I wrote a small plugin to add a button to ckeditor, so that the user can add a tooltip-codesnippet into the editor. This works perfect. After closing the dialog the code is correctly inserted. When I save afterward the text my site is reloading and my data-attributes are gone.

In my plugin I added:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('tooltip', {
        lang: [ 'en', 'de'],
        init: function (editor) {
            editor.addCommand('tooltip', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('tooltip', {
        allowedContent: 'span[data-hint-content]; sup'
            }));
```

And also in my used yaml-config I added:

```
editor:
  config:
    allowedContent: 'span[data-*](*){*}; sup'
```

I'm in a TYPO3 context with Version 8.x.

I already tried to change allowedContent to extraAllowedContent. But this doesn't help. I noticed, that my yaml-config is working by allowing the tags span or sup. But cannot allow the attributes. Also tried to use span[*] oder span[data-*]. No success.

I eather tried this here:
[TYPO3: CKEditor strips data-attributes in -Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55041254/typo3-ckeditor-strips-data-attributes-in-span-tags)

Does anybody had equal problems?

Comment: [try this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22393931/4051471)

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to modify the config of the HTMLparser_db. Just add the following code to the yaml-config:

```
processing:
    HTMLparser_db:
        tags:
            span:
                allowedAttribs: "class, id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, itemscope, itemtype, itemprop, data-target, data-toggle, data-hint-content"
```